# Show excel contextual tab by default

Tags: excel, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am trying to create new excel web-add in using JavaScript (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/contextual-tabs).

 But I am not sure how I can display the contextual tab automatically at the time of load of excel document.
I tried

 `await Office.ribbon.requestCreateControls(contextualTab);`

 in `Office.onReady` but still the tab does not show immediately.

 It works when I click on the task pane command button.
Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve by creating a CustomTab entry in manifest.xml file is instead of creating it programmatically